# Combine the results of two columns in a select into one array with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I'm looking to select both string columns and put it all into a single array of strings.  Right now I'm having to do two selects and combine the results.  It isn't a huge deal, I just think it looks awkward.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish the same goal with one linq statement?  Here is a test case I'm using to mess around:

```
[TestFixture]
  public class test {

    public class Values {
      public string Present { get; set; }
      public string Previous { get; set; }
      public bool Flag { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void test1() {

      var list = new List<Values> {
        new Values { Present = "present1", Previous = "previous1", Flag = false },
        new Values { Present = "present2", Previous = "previous2", Flag = false },
        new Values { Present = "present3", Previous = "previous3", Flag = true },
        new Values { Present = "present4", Previous = "previous4", Flag = true }
      };


      var r1 = list.Where(c => c.Flag).Select(c => c.Present);
      var r2 = list.Where(c => c.Flag).Select(c => c.Previous);
      var combined = r1.Concat(r2);

      Assert.AreEqual(4, combined.Count());
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's clear and beautiful, don't see any reason to change anything here honestly.

Comment: Your assert will fail because `.Union()` removes duplicates.  Maybe you want [`.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)?

Comment: I was not aware of .Union() removing duplicates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative solution with using `SelectMany` (it keeps the duplicates):

```
var combined = list.Where(c => c.Flag)
                   .SelectMany(c => new[] { c.Present, c.Previous });
Assert.AreEqual(4, combined.Count());
```

Comment: This is interesting.  This gives me the results I want but not what I expected.  I thought it would give me combined.Count() == 2. Guess not.

Comment: [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) basically "flattens out" the given multiple collections into one collection.

Answer (score 0):

Does the final ordering of the strings in the list matter?  If not, it seems like this would be the clearest way to accomplish this:

```
var strings = new List<String>();
foreach (var value in list.Where(c => c.Flag))
{
    strings.Add(value.Present);
    strings.Add(value.Previous);
}
```